# Finding the minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be $3$ real numbers satisfying $2 \leq ab+bc+ca$. Find the minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$.

I've been trying to solve this, but I don't really know how to approach this. I thought of $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ca)$, but that gives me  $a+b+c$, which is unknown. How can I solve this?

Comment: How about $$(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge0$$

Comment: You can also use the Rearrangement inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) to solve this question if you know it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice that by [Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) we know that:
$$ 
2ab \leq a^2+b^2; 
\\ 
2ac \leq a^2+c^2; 
\\
2bc \leq b^2+c^2; 
$$

so we can conclude that: 
$$ 
2\left(ab+ac+bc\right) 
\leq 
2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\ \ 
\left(ab+ac+bc\right) 
\leq 
\ \ 
\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\ \ \ \ \ 
\ \ \ \ \ 
\ \ \ \ \ 
\ \ \ \  
2
\leq 
\ \ 
\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right) 
.
$$

---

Note that this in-equlality is sharp for $a=b=c=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$;
for which one can see the value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is equal to $2$.

Answer (score 4):

Famke's answer is the simplest; however, we can use a variational argument, as well.

For all variations that maintain $ab+bc+ca=2$, we have
$$
(b+c)\,\delta a+(a+c)\,\delta b+(a+b)\,\delta c=0\tag{1}
$$
To minimize $a^2+b^2+c^2$, we must have
$$
2a\,\delta a+2b\,\delta b+2c\,\delta c=0\tag{2}
$$
for all variations that satisfy $(1)$.

Orthogonality says that to have $(2)$ for all variations that satisfy $(1)$, we need
$$
2a=\lambda(b+c),\quad2b=\lambda(a+c),\quad\text{and}\quad2c=\lambda(a+b)\tag{3}
$$
Summing these up, we get that $\lambda=1$, and then solving the equations, we get that $a=b=c$. Finally, to satisfy the constraint for $(2)$, we get that $a=b=c=\sqrt{\frac23}$. Thus, the minimum of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is $2$.

Comment: My dear robjohn♦ your solution is more creative and interesting.

Comment: Robjohn.Very elegant solution, Peter

Answer (score 3):

Scalar product:

Let $\vec A : = (a,b,c)$, $\vec B: = (b,c,a)$.

$|\vec A \cdot \vec B| \le |A| |B| $.

$\Rightarrow$  :

$2 \le ab +bc + ca \le a^2 +b^2 + c^2$.

Equality:

$a=b=c = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by your starting step.

Indeed, by C-S
$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc).$$
Thus,
$$3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)$$ or
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+ac+bc$$ and since $ab+ac+bc\geq2,$ we obtain:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq2.$$
The equality occurs for $(1,1,1)||(a,b,c)$ and $ab+ac+bc=2$,

which says that $2$ is a minimal value.

Answer (score 1):

Again from Cauchy-Schwarz from a different perspective

$\sqrt{a^2c^2}+\sqrt{b^2c^2}+\sqrt{a^2c^2} \leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

$a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ac \ge 2$

$a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge 2$

İnequality holds for $a=b=c=\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}$